# AngularJS execute a function after the completion of another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, asynchronous, promise

I execute a function that calls **two functions** sequentially, to run the second function should first finish the first one. But this does not happen, perhaps because the first function is asynchronous. I read that I need to use **"promise"** I tried it, in different way, but it doesn't works. So I rewrote the function as I initially wrote:

```
function fail() { 
    // Get the snackbar DIV
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")

    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";

    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");}, 3000);   

}

function _goback(){
    $location.url('/app/dispensers');
}    

//Check if the item is still available (if nobody bought it)
function _checkavailability(response){
    if (response.data == ""){
              console.log("Accesso non autorizzato")
    }
    $scope.infoproductbyid = response.data;
    if($scope.infoproductbyid.purchaseTime == null){
        console.log("Item disponibile");
        //if the item is available, it's possible to proceeds to checkout
        $location.url('/app/notregcheckout');
    }
    else{
        console.log("Spiacente, item non più disponibile");
      //  localStorage.clear("tokenidproduct");
        //_showSB();  
        fail();
        _goback();
    }    
}
```

In the last rows, you can see that I call `fail()` function for first, and `_goback()` function for second. I want that `_goback()`starts when `fail()`finish, but `fail()` contains a **timeout**, and I think that for this reason the function is asynchronous. I don't understand how I can do

Comment: You can put _goback(); function inside of fail() function time out function   like     setTimeout(function() {
            x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
            _goback();
        }, 3000);

Comment: I already tryed in this way;
' setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); _goback();}, 3000);'
but in this case _goback() doesn't works

Comment: THe second function doesn't start in this way

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Then put another setTimeout like setTimeout(function() {
            x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
            setTimeout(function(){
              _goback();  
          },0)
            
        }, 3000);

Comment: No error, but for example I execute the function "_checkavailability()" after clicking a botton. Thus, if a click the button in this way, "fail()" works, but "_goback()" doesn't works. If I click again, "fail()" doesn't works and ""_goback()" works

Comment: putting the other setTimeout I have the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145817/discussion-between-anupan-and-alfonso-silvestri).

Comment: Ok sorry, I wrong to write. but it doesn't works too. no mistakes

Comment: Why did you tag the question [tag:promise] but don't use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to create a promise:

```
function fail() { 
    // Get the snackbar DIV
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")

    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";

    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
    var promise = $timeout(function() {
      x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
    }, 3000);

    //RETURN promise   
    return promise;
}
```

Then use the `.then` method to wait:

```
fail().then(function() {
    _goback();
});
```

Comment: ' $timeout is not defined'

Comment: ok, I injected $timeout in the function of the controller:
.controller("CartController", function($scope, $filter, $http, $location, $stateParams, restService, $timeout) {  

Thank you, it works fine now